# Select main substring of words from string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to get the 'main' substring from a string. I'm using python and I think regular expressions could help me here. I need to start matching at a word and stop matching at a later point in the string where there are no longer any words in the string

So, for example:

```
"  , ? -- Mr. Smith . ? " -> "Mr. Smith"

" New ------- York " -> "New ------- York"
```

This is obviously way uglier than anything I'll be using this on but I'm hoping it gets the point across, I need it to match at the first word and then stop matching after the last word in the string but it needs to contain every character in between those two

Thanks if anyone can help!

Answer (score 1):

Guess `'\w.*\w'` should work

```
>>> re.search(r'\w.*\w', "  , ? -- Mr. Smith . ? ").group(0)
'Mr. Smith'
```

Comment: the string `A` will not match

Comment: @Aserre Yes, you right. Then nothing to do but to accept your answer :)

Comment: but you can use maybe `\b.*\w`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following regex

```
\w+(?:.*\w)?
```

([TEST IT HERE](https://regex101.com/r/oYMUqG/4))

It captures 1 or more word characters (`\w+`) followed by 1 or 0 occurences of the pattern `.*\w` (0 or more characters with a word character at the end). The `(?: ... )` syntax indicates a non-capturing group.

Sample output :

```
  , ? -- Mr.. Smith . ? --> Mr.. Smith
" New ------- York "    --> New ------- York
a                       --> a
 ('( a::'---'           --> a
?..-t- !                --> t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it very simply without regex:

```
from string import punctuation

s = "  , ? -- Mr. Smith . ? "
print(s.strip(punctuation + ' ')
```

Output is:

```
'Mr. Smith'
```

For string `" New ------- York "`, output is `'New ------- York'`.